# Percentage of acute triangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, planar-graphs

There are 100 dots in a surface. A math lover draw all the triangles possible such that the vertices of the triangle will be those dots. X is the maximum percentage of acute triangles in those triangles. How do you will find X?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: More discussion can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316613/acute-triangles-from-100-points)

Comment: What kind of surface? How do you measure angles in a surface?